# TEXTSPLIT inside CHOOSECOLS inside another TEXTSPLT isn't working as expected

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For an example, string **A,B;C**

I am doing this formula, `=TEXTSPLIT(CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT("A,B;C",","),2),";")`

`TEXTSPLIT` inside will give 2 element column array **A** and **B;C**
Then, `CHOOSECOLS(*,2)` over it will give **B;C** since it is the 2nd element in the array

It is ok till now. If I `TEXTSPLIT` over this with **;** as a separator, then I expect again a 2-element column array **B** and **C**. Instead, I get only the first element as result, that is **B**. What is going wrong here? Is it a bug? I know if I do like `TEXTSPLIT("A,B;C",{",",";"})`, I will get my result, but I have a different sort of scenario. My actual text looks more like **A,B,C;D,E,F**, and I need **D E F** as array. If I do something like `=TEXTSPLIT(CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT("A,B,C;D,E,F",";"),2),",")`, I get only **D**, instead of expected array

Another observation I had is that, if I spilt the operation into 2, say I put the result of `CHOOSECOL` in a cell, and do another `TEXTSPLIT` in another cell, I get the result. But I don't want to do it in another cell.

Comment: You may need `BYROW()` function. What result do you finally expect from input `A,B;C`.

Comment: A column array with elements B & C (don't need A)

Comment: Interesting. The issue is that `CHOOSECOLS` is returning an *array*, albeit one comprising only a single element, i.e. `{"B;C"}` as opposed to the *string* `"B;C"`. Suggest switching to `INDEX`, i.e. `=TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT("A,B;C",","),2),";")`, since `INDEX` here does not result in an array. I've noticed similar behaviour from legacy functions such as `ROW` in certain constructions. Thanks for bringing this issue to light.

Comment: Just a fyi, but why not something much more simple like `=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("A,B,C;D,E,F",";"),",")`? Is your data structured differently at times? If you can have more semi-colon delimited pieces of text and you are looking for a 2nd 'word', maybe use `=INDEX(TEXTSPLIT("A,B,C;D,E,F",",",";"),2)`

Comment: @JosWoolley, interesting 'bug' indeed. I find there are still plentyfull little anoying bugs with these new functions. Here is another one that irritates me `=TEXTSPLIT("AbC","b",,,1)`.

Comment: @JvdV Haha! That's actually quite amusing! But yes, it's clear that between us we're uncovering quite a few bugs relating to the new array functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case using the [Implicit Intersection operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34) (@) solves your problem. Just add to your formula the `@`-operator before `CHOOSECOLS`:

```
=TEXTSPLIT(@CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT("A,B;C",","),2),";")
```

Output:
[image: excel output]

`CHOOSECOLS` returns `1x1` array and `TEXTSPLIT` as its name indicates, it operates at a text (string) level. The `@`-operator converts the array into a string. We would expect here that Excel would do the cast for us, but it doesn't happen.

You can check the above rationale by looking at the steps Excel carries out via *Evaluate Formula* functionality:

The intermediate result after `CHOOSECOLS` call`:
[image: Evaluate formula 1]

The intermediate result after `@`-Operator:
[image: Excel Formula 2]

It is the same intermediate result as @JosWoolley's answer using `INDEX`.

Comment: Should that not be 'Intersection' operator, as opposed to 'Interception'? Anyway, nice use of it, whatever it's called!

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, simply replace `CHOOSECOLS` with `INDEX`:

```
=TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT("A,B,C;D,E,F",";"),2),",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",,CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT("A,B;C",","),2)),";")
```

`CONCAT()` may also work.

```
=TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT("A,B;C",","),2)),";")
```

[image]